# How can I use Akka.NET lighthouse with hyperion

Tags: akka.net, akka.net-cluster

Currently I'm using the akka.net lighthouse docker image which is on [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/petabridge/lighthouse). Together with Akka.Bootstrap.Docker it's nice to override akka hocon configuration from the environment variables. I've set the following environment variables in my k8s deployment file

```yaml
 - name: AKKA__ACTOR__SERIALIZERS__HYPERION
   value: "\"Akka.Serialization.HyperionSerializer, Akka.Serialization.Hyperion\""
 - name: AKKA__ACTOR__SERIALIZATION-BINDINGS__System__Object
   value: hyperion
```

But if I want to enable hyperion serialization it fails with the following message:

> The type name for serializer 'hyperion' did not resolve to an actual Type: 'Akka.Serialization.HyperionSerializer, Akka.Serialization.Hyperion'

The documentation of Akka.NET Lighthouse is very scarce so does anyone of you know how I can use hyperion serialization with Akka.NET lighthouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka.NET is trying to load hyperion serializer via `Type.GetType("Akka.Serialization.HyperionSerializer, Akka.Serialization.Hyperion")` call, and fails to do that, because Lighthouse docker image does not include [Akka.Serialization.Hyperion](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Akka.Serialization.Hyperion/) package.

So what you need to do is:

1. Clone [Lighthouse](https://github.com/petabridge/lighthouse) repo and add [Akka.Serialization.Hyperion](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Akka.Serialization.Hyperion/) package to Lighthouse project references
2. Build your own docker image and use it instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was already suspecting this :-). I'm now implementing this. Will let you know the results.

Comment: This indeed fixes these errors, thanks for pointing towards and confirming this solution direction together with updating the documentation of lighthouse :-)